# Chaining promises in React for REST API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am designing an application in React right now and I am kind of new to React so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I am building components that rely on making various Rest API calls to get the data they need to display. Pretty standard stuff.

However, before the server will give me access to any of the resources I need to make an authentication call to retrieve an API token. The API token expires every 4 hours so I also need to check it's still valid.

I am using `fetch` to get the API token successfully, and using that API token I can also successfully get the resources I require. The problem is that `fetch` is an async promise, meaning when the application loads it will fire a request for the API token AND fire the request for the resource long before I have access to the API token. The API token will need to be set in the Redux (or possibly hooks) state so all components have access to it, but how to I tell the other API calls to wait for the auth call to finish before they go? I realise I could stick the second API call inside a `.then()` but this is almost certainly wrong and feels messy.

I assume this is a common thing people face, what is the standard approach to this problem?

Comment: how about separating the auth call and resource call into separate components? The auth component would wrap the resource component and not render the resource component until the token is set in the auth component's state. Then the auth component passes the token to the rendered resource component

Comment: You can rely on **callbacks** if it looks less messy to you, though using `.then()` is not wrong. Also, the approach @bsapaka purposed is also good.

Answer (score 0):

```
let self = this;
fetch('/yourAuthUrl')
    then(function() { //Wait auth result
         //HERE UPDATE YOUR STATE WITH TOKEN (i think with connect plugin if u need redux)
         const req1 = fetch('/yourApiUrlWithToken')
         const req2 = fetch('/yourApiUrlWithToken')
         const req3 = fetch('/yourApiUrlWithToken')
         const req4 = fetch('/yourApiUrlWithToken')
         Promise.all([req1,req2,req3,req4]) //Wait all api request
             .then(function() {
                 //HERE UPDATE YOUR STATE FOR RENDER (i think with connect plugin if u need redux)
             });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `.then()`.

Here is way to do it without looking so messy.

```js
const fetchToken = (onFetchCallback) => {
  fetch('/yourTokenAPI').then(token => {
    onFetchCallback(token);
  });
};

const fetchResource = (token) => {
  // Perform a request to your resource api
  // using the parameter 'token'
  // It could be a fetch call
  performRequestToApi(token)
}

const mainRoutine = () => {
  // You can pass a reference of the method
  // responsible for fetching the resource
  fetchToken(fetchResource);

  // You can declare a method and inside of it
  // perform a call to 'fetchResource'
  fetchToken((value) => {
    fetchResource(value);
  });

  // Same as before, but with ES5 syntax
  fetchToken(function(value) {
    fetchResource(value)
  })
}
```

Here is an example of how your component should look like.

```js
const Component = ({ token, ...props }) => {

  // It is important that you use props and parameters
  // so React can re render the component as the property changes
  const renderComponent = token => {
    // If the token is not defined yet,
    // then you can return null or do
    // something else indicating that
    // there is no token
    if (!token) return null;

    // In case token is defined,
    // you should return or component
    // using the props you want ('...props')
    return <React.Fragment>Here goes your component</React.Fragment>;
  };

  return <React.Fragment>{renderComponent(token)}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

**And when you call your component inside of your page, you have to pass the token you just got using those fetch methods you defined before.**

```js
<Component token={yourTokenVariable} />
```